# Using a Regular expression to extract required data

Tags: regex, vba, excel

I am trying to modify my current regular expression to be more exclusive.

This is what I have so far:

```
RE.Pattern = "(L\d{1}-\w{2}-\w{4,7}-DATA-\d{3,4})"
```

What this does is extracts the following examples of strings from a load of junk data. FYI these strings are **NOT** static, the number values etc will change between cells.

```
L2-R2-TEST-DATA-4724
L1-SR-TESTING-DATA-472
L1-R2-WORKING-DATA-472
```

The above strings are what I want, however as well as this it will also extract the data below:

```
L1-R2-WRONGON-DATA-4725
L2-SR-RUBBISH-DATA-472
```

This is not what I need, and was wondering what, if anything, could be done in order to modify my regex to stop this from happening...

I was wondering if it is possible to statically define say TEST,TESTING and WORKING somehow within the original regex? So that I can grab them and not WRONGON and RUBBISH.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a non-capturing group `(?:` to separate what words you want to include. Also its not necessary to have `L\d{1}`, you can simply use `L\d`

```
RE.Pattern = "(L\d-\w{2}-(?:TEST(?:ING)?|WORKING)-DATA-\d{3,4})"
```

See [`Live demo`](http://regex101.com/r/yT7oD2)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your question, since you say that the strings will be changing, but you want to know if you can statically match specific cases.

If you just want to match `TEST`, `TESTING` and `WORKING`, you can replace `\w{4,7}` with `(?:TEST|TESTING|WORKING)` and it will obviously not match `WRONGON` or `RUBBISH`. If you want to match any 4-7 character word *except* the latter two, that's a different matter.